# 220 / 110 acv home voltage stabilization

Tags: electrical-panel

I am trying to find an in-line home  power voltage regulator  for my house . I am looking  to put it in after my city meter  , but before my home fuse box . I want to make the city voltage stable . my 110 ac volts will range from 111 to 124 ac line volts . I find this wide range is to hard on my LED lights . I have 6 battery powered backups for computer , tv , and other electronics .
I think if I get a whole house stabilizer to set / adjust it for 110 and 220 ac it might help some problems .

Will this hook up to my 220 house line so I can set my ac volts to 109 or 110 volts ?  Also help with power surges ??

Comment: Are you in the US or Canada? Here the nominal voltage is 120/240V, NOT 110/220V. 111-124V is perfectly normal.

Comment: Plenty of LEDs are actually 80-280VAC 47-63 Hz input - are you quite sure yours are so sensitive (or that what is killing them, if they are dying, is voltage variation, and not excessive heat?) Also what is the amperage of your service?

Comment: This could be an extremely expensive way to solve your apparent problem.

Comment: If you really want to do that, look for a ferroresonant transformer.   I  can pretty much guarantee that you won't like the electric bill after installing one, plan on it doubling at least.  Your listed voltage deviations are completely normal, and shouldn't affect anything though.

Comment: Unless you've got some industrial grade battery backups then your devices behind them are still going to feel the voltage fluctuations you described.  Consumer grade battery backups only draw from the battery when the AC goes out.

Answer (score 2):

If the LEDs are driven by a low voltage power supply, you could just get a high quality regulated power supply that supplies a tightly controlled output voltage irrespective of the input voltage fluctuations.  If your LED lights are on regular 120V fixtures, it's a harder problem.

A whole-house solution is possible but probably impractical, it would have to be rated for the full amperage of your service, which would be very expensive.

You can could have a power conditioner installed for lighting circuits, it wouldn't be too bad to install one or two.

If you use dual conversion "online" UPS's, they can correct for low voltage for the loads that they power.  Line interactive UPS's generally do not.  That would be helpful for the electronics, or for the LED lights if they run off a corded power supply.

Comment: Most modern computer supplies (switch mode power supplies) likewise are not at all picky about the voltage or frequency they are supplied with, and changing it anywhere inside their accepted range has no effect on their output voltages.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to talk to your power company, not SE.  Though it may be worth revisiting your measurement methods, those look odd to me.   124V is a 3.3% deviation from target 120V, no biggie.  The 111v is a bit concerning, but could be accounted for by voltage drop in your house's wiring on a big load like a heater, perhaps combined with a slight sag from your power company due to everyone else pulling big loads too.  I really don't know how you're measuring this.

However, these small deviations will not blow equipment, least of all equipment which uses electronic switching power supplies and is probably rated for a far wider range of voltage.  I would be more suspicious of voltage spikes or line noise - particularly from whichever loads are pulling your voltage down to 111V.  A 260V spike isn't going to faze a world-market LED, but a 600V spike might.

One very new product of interest is whole-house power monitoring.  This attaches to a 240V 2-pole breaker (for monitoring) and clamps ammeter sensors around the supply cables.  Then it data-logs, and shares its data with your smartphone/tablet app and the cloud via WiFi. Aside from power quality, it can pick out individual appliances by their current-draw patterns.  It will give you very solid voltage and spike data to bring to your power company.

One option is a whole-house surge suppressor.  They come in several variants.  One mounts underneath your electric meter - you'll need to talk to the power company about that.  Another wires into your service panel via a 240V 2-pole breaker.  It really doesn't matter which side of the breaker it's on, a breaker is just a switch and when closed, it's connected. Of course you can get per-outlet surge suppressors easily enough, as well as power strips that claim to surge-suppress (I have my doubts).

Of course, all these devices simply go in parallel to the power bus, none actually force the power to flow through them, like a transformer does. Transformers suppress surges very well, and an extreme option is to get a transformer dedicated to your house - or at least to a panel feeding your sensitive loads.  You'd need a 25 KVA transformer for 100A service, 50 KVA for 200A service, or 5 KVA transformers are often seen cheap on Craigslist.

Why is it 120V/240V and not 110/220?   Back when the first 60 cycle AC power systems were being built, they pegged standard voltage at 100 volts, nice round number.  But they wanted to distribute more power.  Watts = volts x amps.  To increase amps, they need thicker wires.  To increase volts, they only need better insulation, and they already had it, as insulation is wildly overdesigned because it's cheap to do so.  But big voltage changes would damage loads (i.e. light bulbs, AC power was all about lighting at the time).  So they did a little bump to 105V, a few years later to 110V.  This is when power started going into the common man's home in earnest, so "110V" entered the popular vernacular.  There were subsequent bumps to 115V, 117.5V and 120V with a few places toying with a bump to 125V before national standards swept in and pegged it at 120V.

One nice thing about your own transformer is there are a series of taps to adjust output voltage plus or minus 10% in several steps.  So you can have 110v actual, *if you really want it*.

Selling into the world market, most countries are 220-240V with as low as 100v (Japan). There is also 277V which is one leg of 480V 3-phase, often used for lighting circuits.  When a manufacturer uses a switching power supply, they typically range it to allow 90-264 volts (or 90-305V in lighting) - every major voltage +/- 10%.  Since they're switching power supplies, they don't care about Hz - I know people who plug LED bulbs and laptop power supplies into 75 volts DC and they work.  Slightly out of band, but it works.